# How to create mysql event which execute itself every last sunday of every last month in every quarter of the year on a specific time?

Tags: mysql, mysql-event

I'm trying to create mysql event which will execute itself every last sunday of the last month of every quarter in the year on a specific time, but i can't figure out how to create such schedule. Is there any options to set up schedule in such a complicated way?

Comment: You could create a daily event and test within it whether code should run or not